# Registering per-class handlers

Tags: python, decorator, handler

I'm trying to find a good way to easily register handlers of some commands in a Python class. Those handlers would be registered for subclasses of `SomeBaseClass` and only available there. Unfortunately I'm starting to think I'm doing way more work than necessary. Right now, I've got:

```
def register_handlers(cls):
    cls._handlers = {}
    for method in cls.__dict__.values():
        if hasattr(method, "handler_name"):
            cls._handlers[method.handler_name] = method
    return cls

class SomeBaseClass(object):
    _handlers = None
    def __init__(self):
        for h in self._handlers:
            self._handlers[h] = types.MethodType(self._handlers[h], self, SomeBaseClass)
    def run_action(self, name, *args):
        return self._handlers[name](*args)

def actual_handler_wrapper(f):
    ....
    f.handler_name = name
    ....
```

There are a couple of issues here:

- both the class and it's handlers have to be decorated
- second level of subclasses is not easily available (`_handlers` would have to be assigned and checked on every level of inheritance)
- binding handlers to a class during initialisation seems dirty...

Is there some way to improve this? I could probably get rid of `register_handlers` by changing `SomeBaseClass` to be a meta-class. It could also bind handlers at class creation time. But that seems even more complicated than the current approach.

Is there some easier way out?

Edit: Sample usage:

```
@register_handlers
class SubClass(SomeBaseClass):
    @actual_handler_wrapper
    def handler(self):
       ...
```

Comment: What kind of pattern are you abstracting like this? Is the goal to write `handler = SomeBaseClass._registry[some_name]` later? Or something different?

Comment: Is `@register_handlers` supposed to be above `class SomeBaseClass(object)`? And what is `cn`?

Comment: `cn` was a copy&paste mistake. I'm trying to make the functions registered for a general dispatch function in `SomeBaseClass`, which will pass external requests to some `self._handlers[action_name]`.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking the problem. If you have one handler per action, then just make up a naming convention for them, like this:

```
class SomeBaseClass(object):
    def run_action(self, name, *args):
        getattr(self, name + '_handler')(*args)

class SubClass(SomeBaseClass):
    def foo_handler(self):
        # called on run_action('foo')
```

Then again, you might just drop the `run_action` method altogether, but I guess that depends on how it's going to be called, and on your personal preferences.

Comment: True, this might be easier way to approach the problem. However I'm still interested if I can simplify the 'registry' approach somehow...

Comment: @viraptor: Using naming convention and a metaclass will get rid of the decorators. Or reduce them to one class decorator if you don't want to use a metaclass. Still, it just duplicates what Python already does for you, why bother?

Comment: Easier introspection, no accidental collisions with future users of the classes, being more explicit about things in general, being able to make an action named `some we!%d string`... and many other reasons.